# No media found error while booting from live usb

Tags: 12.04, lts

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from live usb disk. While booting from usb I am getting error as "/init line 7 cannot open /dev/sdb: no media found".

My machine is currently dual boot with Windows-7 and Fedora 17.

I wanna get rid of Fedora ASAP.

I am using SanDisk cruiserBlade 4 GB media.

I used UNetBootin for creating live usb from ISO file.

Please help me resolve this problem ASAP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've had better luck [downloading the .iso](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and using

```
sudo dd if=<ubuntu.iso> of=</dev/sdb>
```

where  is the file name and location of the .iso and  is the USB you want to completely overwrite with the contents of the .iso file. unetbootin just doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing bug 817145, do add yourself to the "affects me" on the bug.  The 13.04 does not seem to have this problem, but if you really want the 12.04 LTS version, I found that when the error appears, a quick pull the USB install media and immediate reinsert it allowed the boot to continue, and install successfully.